# jquery HOWTO select a node and clone it ,then remove a button finally insert into another node

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

below is part of html code

```
<div id="test1"><span><input type='text' name='add'/><input type='text' name='del'/><span></div>

<div id="container"></div>
```

i tried to use jquery to clone #test1 node and remove the add button then add the result to #container i tried write the code like belows,but it seems didn't work

```
$("#test1").clone().remove("input[name='add']").appendTo("#container")
```

hope someone could help,i have re-edited the question

Comment: I'm a little confused by your wording...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var t1 = $("#test1").clone();
$("input[name='add']", t1).remove();
$(t1).appendTo("#container");
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function:

```
var str = html.replace("<input type='text' name='add'/>", "");
```

**Result:**

```
<div><span><input type='text' name='del'/>
```

If you have more than one of those instances, you can use regex with `/g` modifier:

```
var str = html.replace(/<input type='text' name='add'\/>/g, "");
```

**Result:**

```
<div><span><input type='text' name='del'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(':button').remove();` or `$('input[type="button"]').remove()` will probably do what you're looking for.

Comment: `html` is a string not a jquery object for `remove` to work at it.

Comment: my html is a string not the dom in a web page,so my question is how to let my html became a dom then jquery could operate it